# sudo -i and ~/.pam_environment

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, login, pam

I have switched to using `~/.pam_environment` for setting my user environment variables, and it works quite well. PAM takes care of setting everything, regardless of what shell I'm using, how I'm using it, ect. The one place where I've noticed an issue is when opening an interactive shell with `sudo -i`; It seems as though `~/.pam_environment` is not used. For example, if I'd like to switch to user `foo`, I'd run `sudo -iu foo`. After doing so, none of the environment variables specified in `/home/foo/.pam_environment` are set.

All I've found pertaining to this subject is the fact that `sudo` will not carry over most (if not all) environment variables to the created process. However, I don't want to carry over the old environment variables; I just want to honor the ones of the user I'm changing to.

Is there a way to do this? Is there a reason (security?) that this is not the default behavior?

Comment: I figured out a way to do it: add `session required pam_env.so user_readenv=1` to `/etc/pam.d/sudo`. This works, but I still want to know if I'm violating any security rule by doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Sudo environment variables are controlled by sudoers file. As per [sudoers's man page](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#Command_environment). By default, sudoers file have the `env_reset` option enabled, and as such, an minimal environment is set. You can whitelist variables by means of `env_check` and `env_keep` options. Also, sudo's PATH is controlled by `secure_path` option.

Comment: Right, this is what I keep finding. But I don't want to have the child process inherit the environment variables of the parent process. I want the child process to set the environment variables specified in `~/.pam_environment`.